# Get data from one url by using custom url pattern wp

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Can anybody suggest me this-

[example.com/topic/a-1.html](http://example.com/topic/a-1.html) using this url i want to get data from
[example.com/topic?page=a&number=1](http://example.com/topic?page=a&number=1)  in wp.
I tried wp rewrite functions but that could not helped me.

& I tried this too.

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*).html$ /topic?page=$1&num=$2 [L]
Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well finally i got this rule.
i was missing **index.php** thats why wp was redirecting to 404.
RewriteRule ^topic/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php/topic?page=$1&num=$2 [L]

Finally it worked for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you set `permalinks` in `options`, all links in your site will have the form `site.com/page`, but if you need delivery `get` parameter you can do it anyway, adding at the end of the `get` request `site.com/page?id=1&page=2`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I have created a custom plugin that retunrs data using this url example.com/topic?page=a&number=1.
But i have to change the url to example.com/topic/a-1.html to get the same data with the same pattern eg(a,b, c...1,2,3...).
If i change the wp url with the custom , wp returns 404.

Comment: @Gauravkumar I didn't understand what you want to do. Explain more please.

Comment: @nikitadurarev- As i have mentioned , i have created a custom plugin that returns tag list, and i have added pagination there in a way that it gets data according to alphabetical order and index position.
eg: site.com/wp_post_page(topic)?id=1&page=A  and thats working fine.
Now i need to change the url like site.com/post_page/page-id.html
to fetch the same data as before.
So i need to know , how to do this in wp without using ajax??

Comment: @Gauravkumar You will need to go to site.com/post_page/page-id.html?id=1 and process the GET request in your plugin. You do not mind .html?

Comment: yup we need that,but let say we need data from 
site.com/page/{page}-{id}, then how ll i get it from site.com/page/?page=A&num=4

Comment: @Gauravkumar You need to parse the information on the first site, then configure it in an array and then in the handler substitute the same data that was on the old site in url

Comment: i used this 
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/])/([^/]).html$ /topic?page=$1&num=$2 [L
but that did not work, can you suggest others??

Comment: @Gauravkumar Do you know what does it mean parsing page? You want to register a rule in htaccess. Although you are referring to another site. These are different things.

Comment: so how to do it now??  how wp uses routing rule to customizes its url?? 
i want to do the same to fetch my data /

Comment: @Gauravkumar Do you have a function that processes this data?

Comment: yup i have , but for that i have to read the url.
in  my case when i write custom url (site.com/posts/{page}-{num} it throws 404. if any how i managed to be on the same page then i can fetch the data using my code.
So basically i dont need 404 when i made my custom url.
As you know wp has the same functionality (Permalink) where it can fetch data from site.com/?p=22827 and site.com/{page-name} .
I think you got my point. Thanks

Comment: @Gauravkumar If you want to go to URL site.com/posts/{page}-{num}, you must have a record in the database that will link to this page. But if you want to process GET request, you need to specify request site.com/posts/{page}-{num}?get. 404 error occurs because there is no record in the database.